# Rails - Proper way to route an action in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to create a button that performs some actions from my controller when clicked, but I'm getting some routing errors.

The button in the view looks like...

```
  <%= button_to "Thumbs Up", {:controller => 'user', :action => "yes", :id => event.id}  %>
```

The view is the index page of the my user controller.  Within the user controller I have an action called "yes" that makes changes to a record depending on which Event(the model being displayed on the index page) item is picked.  SO the controller action in the controller looks like....

```
def yes
  @user = User.find(current_user)
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
 ........ Blah Blah Blah .....
  redirect_to home_path
end
```

The home path is just routing to the user#index view

So for the route I have is ....

```
  match '/yes' => 'user#yes'.
```

But I get the error "No route matches {:controller=>"user/user", :action=>"yes", :id=>1}"

So how do I create a button and route that goes to a specific action in my controller and passes the id as the parameter so the action can work its magic and redirect to the same page?

Comment: mmm, I see ':controller=>"user/user"', did you namespace or scope some routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  match '/yes(/:id)' => 'user#yes'
```

brackets make params optionnal, see http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html